# Filtering out robot parts from pointcloud data

Tags: urdf, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the recommended way of filtering out robot parts (of which URDF is available) in pointclouds? I am aware of the robot_self_filter package, but this still uses the old PointCloud format and has unstable ROS and C++ APIs per the docs, so I thought that with all the recent advances in RGB-D sensors/PCL etc. there might be alternatives.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9656/filtering-out-robot-parts-from-pointcloud-data/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-04-06**:
Well, 24 hours without an answer. I would take that as confirmation that the `robot_self_filter` package is still the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin,

The documentation on the wiki is outdated. The robot_self_filter does subscribe to PointCloud2 messages now.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-04-08**:
Oh ok, thanks. That'll teach me to look into the wiki ..better to directly look at source code hehe.